# How can I create an AngularJS directive that will show if my data is loading or fetching?

Tags: angularjs

My application sets the values of $scope.loading or $scope.fetching to more than zero if data is being loaded or fetched.

I have the following that I coded in HTML:

```
<div class="activity-mask" 
     data-ng-show="creating!=0">
     <span>Creating...</span>
</div>
<div class="activity-mask" 
     data-ng-show="loading!=0">
     <span>Loading...</span>
</div>
<div class="activity-mask" 
     data-ng-show="fetching!=0">
     <span>Fetching...</span>
</div>
```

I have these coded in many places in my application. Could / should I code this in a directive? What I have is working quite good but can anyone suggest something better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use events to announce state changes like that. Using a model property requires you to always have a clear line of inheritance down the scope tree between your directive and that model. Which might work fine. But event systems are a bit more flexible, and allow your components to operate independent of an assumed context. What happens if you decide to move your data loader to a service that doesn't have direct access to local $scope? Or trigger a data load in a controller whose scope doesn't inherit from the same branch of the tree as the loader modal? Events to the rescue.

Your directive for the loader might instead be:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('ng-loading', function () {
        return {
            template: <template string>,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.loadCount = 0;
                scope.$on('loadingData', function() {
                    if (scope.loadCount === 0) {
                        element.addClass('visibleLoader');
                    }
                    scope.loadCount++;
                })
                scope.$on('loadComplete', function() {
                    if (scope.loadCount > 0) {
                        scope.loadCount--;
                        if (scope.loadCount === 0) {
                            element.removeClass('visibleLoader');
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    };
})
```

Then, just use `$rootScope.broadcast('loadingData')` from whatever controller or service you're loading the data in. And use the promise pattern to fire the close event when the data load is finished :

```
$http.get('/urlToFetch').then(function(){$rootScope.broadcast('loadComplete')});
```

Loaders are a pretty straightforward pattern where you can generally manage the inheritance issues. (Or, you can even get away with putting it all onto $rootScope.) So, feel free to use model properties if that works for you. But getting used to event-driven systems gives you vastly more flexibility to re-use your directives however and wherever you like. Plus, you can have a cascade of related behaviors that can all key off a single event broadcast, without needing to finagle anything else.

Comment: The problem with this is that I have sometimes multiple loads at the same time. So the way I do this is I increment the value of loading when each starts and decrement when each completes. I like your suggestion but it doesn't really help with my special needs.

Comment: Doesn't really change anything. Just add the logic to increment and decrement the value of `loading` to the event listeners. Actually, it's an even better, clearer case for the benefits of an event system, because you can be firing the 'loading' event from any/all of your controllers and services. You'll be maintaining a central counter of those loading/complete events, and managing the state of the loader visuals from that same location. I'm updating the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Directive Code

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('ng-loading', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: [
            '<div class="activity-mask">',
            '<span>Loading ...</span>',          
            '</div>'
        ].join(''),
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var promiseObj = scope['loading'] || scope['fetching'];
            if (promiseObj && angular.isFunction(promiseObj['finally']) ) {
                promiseObj['finally'](function() {
                  element.addClass('ng-hide'); //hide directive
                });
            }
        }
    };
})
```

;

View Code

`<div ng-loading></div>`

Controller code

```
$scope.fetching = $http.get('/urlToFetch').then(function(){ /* your code */});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have sometimes multiple loads at the same time. So the way I do this is I increment the value of loading when each starts and decrement when each completes. I like your suggestion but it doesn't really help with my special needs.